# Track when adding data member for boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++03

I am looking for any strategies in order to know when someone is adding data members in some classes which are already serialized and forget to serialize it.

For instance, in the following class `bar` was added but not serialized in the access struct.

```
// In implementation library
class A {
public:
    struct access;
    A(float f, int b) : foo(f), bar(b) {}
private:
    float foo;
    int bar; // A user just 'added' bar data member
};

// In serialization library
struct A::access {
    template <class Archive>
    static void serialize(Archive &ar, A &a, const unsigned int) {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a.foo); 
        // bar serialization is missing here but compiler does not complain
    }
};
```

[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a78a2faed0db163)

For instance, is it possible that the compiler throw an error when compiling the serialization library ?

For the moment, the idea I came up with is to add some unit tests which would tell whether a serialized/deserialized scenario would give the right behaviour.

I am looking for something smarter, some simple ways without the need to require to complicated reflection techniques (I cannot use boost in my implementation library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the unit tests are the way to go, really.

In the absence of reflection language facilities, there is no fool-proof way to check what you want¹. What you could do in addition is to statically assert the `sizeof(MyClass)` in your serialization method. Of course, this would not detect changes the leave the net class size unchanged, but it's <strike>better</strike> more than nothing.

Unit tests sidestep all the issues by focusing on the relevant things, instead. I honestly think any more structural verification should be part of code-review.

> **Idea** You could think about adding custom rules to any static-analysis tools you may have (in the future). Static analysis features usually have rich "reflection" information

---

¹ aside from the semantics issues (not every field may need to be serialized in the first place)

Comment: Thanks again for your insights. A coworker also suggested to check the sizeof. I will try that and rely on unit tests. I also keep your idea on using the help of static analysis :)